# How can i use return value of func. as integer with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, func

```
<script>
function returnHEİGHT() {

    if (...)
        return 315;
    else
        return 639;
}
</script>
```

I want to use like this:

```
<video height=returnHEİGHT() width="639" controls>
 <source src="NGC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

I can use return value as string for print  , if u use like this but i want integer value

```
<p id="demo" ></p>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 639;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video id = "videoId"   width="639" controls>
 <source src="NGC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

and you javascript

```
 $("#videoId").css("height", returnHEİGHT()+'px');
```

Comment: thx its work for me , SOLVE 
if u use  this ' $("#videoId").css("height", returnHEİGHT()+'px') ;'
 u should add this
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_ID').setAttribute("style","YOUR STYLES");
```

For example:

```
document.getElementById('demo').setAttribute("style","height:500px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the attributes. 
If you have jquery reference in ur project, then, in document.ready add below,

$("video").attr("height", returnHEİGHT()):